# Java8: Class unloading in G1GC Remark phase taking too long

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We have a Java 8 web service which is using 18GB and other default JVM config. GC pauses are short and normal. But in GC Remark Phase, class unloading is taking a lot of time (see below). This is causing client session to be disconnected. How can we configure GC to reduce class unloading time, or split the time in multiple phases

```
2020-04-21T15:14:15.672+0000: 8165.746: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
2020-04-21T15:14:15.703+0000: 8165.778: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-end, 0.0326298 secs]
2020-04-21T15:14:15.703+0000: 8165.778: [GC concurrent-mark-start]
2020-04-21T15:14:16.032+0000: 8166.102: [GC concurrent-mark-end, 0.3238259 secs]

2020-04-21T15:14:16.032+0000: 8166.106: [GC remark 2020-04-21T15:14:16.032+0000: 8166.106: [Finalize Marking, 0.0011369 secs] 2020-04-21T15:14:16.032+0000: 8166.107: [GC ref-proc, 0.0071566 secs] 2020-04-21T15:14:16.047+0000: 8166.114: [**Unloading, 59.0294601 secs**], 59.0400411 secs]
 [Times: user=1.45 sys=0.38, real=59.04 secs] 

2020-04-21T15:15:15.076+0000: 8225.150: [GC cleanup 2860M->1308M(18G), 0.2443660 secs]
 [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.05, real=0.25 secs]
```

Comment: there are GCs that do that concurrently, btw.

Comment: Even I thought so but when i referred to Oracle documentation they have mentioned:                  Remark phase: This phase is STW collection and helps the completion of the marking cycle. G drains SATB buffers, traces unvisited live objects, and performs reference processing.

Comment: I was saying _other_ GC algorithms, look at Shenandoah GC v2.0 and ZGC

Comment: Ok I will check them. But I am more interested if I can somehow tune the same GC to improve its performance

Comment: Can I enable ZGC in Java8. I tried to search online but did not get any concrete statement

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by class unload. please try add -XX:-ClassUnloading